# Calling Web method from CustomerMobilePOS.aspx returning internal server error 500

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I'm trying to call web method GetValidation from CustomerMobilePOS.aspx from Javascript ajax but it's returning internal server error 500.

Here is the code

```
    public static List<string> GetValidation(string[] productList, string total)
    {
        List<string> lst = new List<string>(productList);
        try
        {
            Persistence obj = new Persistence();

            lst.Add("\n");
            lst.Add("\n" + total);
            string clientContactNo = HttpContext.Current.Session["contactno"].ToString();
            var r = obj.CreateTable();

            //ToDataTable(lst);
            for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
            {
                if ((i + 1) % 4 == 0)
                {
                    DataRow dr = r.NewRow();
                    dr["notes"] = lst[i - 3];
                    dr["quantity"] = lst[i - 2];
                    dr["shipbilling"] = lst[i - 1];
                    dr["itemnumber"] = lst[i];

                    r.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }

            obj.InsertTable(r);
            obj.InsertTable(60, 194184, int.Parse(clientContactNo));
            //Products p = new Products();
            //foreach (var item in prod)
            //{
            //    foreach (var item in p)
            //    {
            //        p.Product.
            //    }
            //}
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // throw;
        }
        return lst;
    }


$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MobileClientPOS.aspx/GetValidation",

        data: JSON.stringify({ productList: productList, total: total }),

        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccessOrderInsertion,
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
```

I have tried everything didn't worked. There's another GetValidation method in main.aspx page which is default page with more parameter. May be it access that method instead of this method in CustomermobilePOS.aspx

Comment: do you have [WebMethod] attribute above your method?

Comment: Yes I have it above this method